# Grails or Gaelyk for medium sized application

Tags: grails, gaelyk

I'm planing to start working on a medium sized application (not too complex but not too simple either) that'll run on the google app engine. I had earlier decided to use Gaelyk because of the support it provides for GAE but I have discovered that it has no templating support. Is Grails then better suited for this purpose? Or can Grails templating be used with Gaelyk as well?

Comment: Can someone create the gaelyk tag please?

Comment: There is a good discussion on this question over here that I recommend to anyone landing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978879/grails-vs-gaelyk-for-new-groovy-appengine-application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the tutorial on the Gaelyk website, you'll notice that the templating system is indeed there and covered.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume. I should have been clearer with the question, i'll be sending a message on the mailing list soon with a clearer question. :)