# Grails - Problem uninstalling Tomcat - Unable to delete catalina-ant.jar

Tags: java, google-app-engine, tomcat, grails, groovy

I am working on a grails app and need to remove Tomcat plugin in order to be able to host on Google App Engine (Also to use Jetty for another project)

As instructed [on Grails app engine documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/app-engine), I need to remove Tomcat as GAE apps only runs on their server.

However, I keep on getting this error (The error message is much longer, only post the first few lines):

```
: Unable to delete file C:\Users\Rama\.grails\1.3.7\projects\ccubemanager\plugins\tomcat-1.3.7\lib\catalina-ant.jar
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.handle(Delete.java:624)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.removeDir(Delete.java:683)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.removeDir(Delete.java:679)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Delete.execute(Delete.java:543)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor47.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I am wondering if deleting the catalina-ant.jar manually would be a wise choice.

I tried to manually delete the whole /plugin directory anyway following [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/upgrade-quick-start-guide-code-to-1-2-0-GRAILS-5342-td1469656.html) and it caused more mess that I cannot run any command on the app:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.math.BigInteger.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [target/classes]
Possible solutions: wait(), abs(), abs(), any(), wait(long), add(java.math.BigInteger)
    at BuildConfig.run(BuildConfig.groovy:1)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:653)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings$loadConfig.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at grails.util.BuildSettings.loadConfig(BuildSettings.groovy:630)
WARNING: There was an error loading the BuildConfig: No signature of method: java.math.BigInteger.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [target/classes]
Possible solutions: wait(), abs(), abs(), any(), wait(long), add(java.math.BigInteger)
```

I also try to start an entirely new project and uninstall tomcat, surprisingly it does not work either?

> I am using Grails 1.3.7; STS 2.6.0; Windows 7

Could anyone please help, thanks alot!!

Comment: I believe there are some issues with OpenJDK and the latest Grails that prevent it working on the App Engine... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978879/grails-vs-gaelyk-for-new-groovy-appengine-application/4979085#4979085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to uninstall tomcat by running the following command from the root of the project `grails uninstall-plugin tomcat`.

This will fail if another process has locked any of the files that the command needs to delete - this could be what is preventing `catalina-ant.jar` from being deleted. There are various tools available for windows that will tell you which process has a lock on a file. I've used [unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) in the past.

Comment: Thanks Don, ill try looking into it
It is kinda strange that these files are locked by default
Fyi I am using STS as IDE